# Help with a subset $A$ of the real line that has four distinctive derived sets distinct from each other.

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question: I need to provide a subset $A$ of the real line that has **four** distinctive derived sets distinct from each other.

I'm stuck at finding the first derived set.

If I let

$\begin{gathered}
  {A^{\left( 4 \right)}} = \left\{ 0 \right\} \hfill \\
  {A^{\left( 3 \right)}} = \left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{ {\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2} \right\} \hfill \\
  {A^{\left( 2 \right)}} = \left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{ {\frac{1}{n}:n \geq 2} \right\} \cup \left\{ {\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k}\left( {\frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right):k \geq 2} \right\} \hfill \\
\end{gathered} $

Then I'm stuck at what ${A^{\left( 1 \right)}} = {A^d}$ will look like, and in return $A$? How do I construct the next set?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Observe what you do when moving from $A^{(3)}$ to $A^{(2)}$. You have $\{0\} ∪ \{\frac{1}{n}: n ∈ ℕ\}$ – a converging sequence. And what you do? To every gap $(\frac{1}{n + 1}, \frac{1}{n})$ you add a new sequence converging to $\frac{1}{n + 1}$ (and you do essentially the same thing for the first element of the sequence). This turns all the previously isolated point into the limit points of the first level… It is not clear how the corresponding formula would look like, but that is not important. The point is the general idea.

Comment: If I did not already know how the corresponding formula would look, this would not be so convincing to me: the general idea is the first point; and converting the general idea into an actual formula is the second, equally important point, i.e. a simple formula for inserting into any gap $(a,b)$ a sequence converging to $a$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: you are right, the second step is not trival or unimportant, but I would say that it is “less creative” and “more mechanical”. You can just take the canonical converging sequence and linearly rescale it to the gap. For me, the formula without the idea behind it would be less convincing.

Comment: @user87690 does  $\left\{ {\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k}\left( {\frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right):k \geq 2} \right\}$ converge to $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @pabhp No, but it does to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @user87690 does the new sequence that I add on have to converge to $\left\{ {\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k}\left( {\frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right):k \geq 2} \right\}$ or does it have to converge to $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @pabhp For each point of each $\{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k}(\frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{1}{n}): k ≥ 1\}$ you add a sequence converging to that point. There is no need to add a sequence converging to $\frac{1}{n + 1}$ – there already is one on the current level. In general, you a add a new sequence for every isolated point.

Comment: @pabhp Yes, it should.

Comment: @pabhp That sounds like the same thing to me.